# Spring JPA - Query against id in a Set of sub entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to figure out how I would go about querying against this type of data structure for all of the Animal objects that have a brownBearId; Using either a jpa repository method or @Query annotation. I'm starting to think it might only be possible by having to query for all Animal objects & then, traverse each sub set to search for the id.

```
@Entity
@Table
class Animal {
  String animalId
  Set<Bear> bears;
  Set<Dog> dogs;
}

class Bear {
  String bearId;
  Set<BrownBear> brownBears;
  Set<PolarBear> polarBears;
}

class BrownBear {
  String brownBearId;
}
```

Any ideas how it might be possible ?

EDIT: The Animal class is the only entity/table. The other sub set<> objects are simply Data Transfer Objects (DTO) that are not JPA entities with any mappings.

Comment: you want all the animals with a particular brownBearId ?
Or
All the animals which have brownBearId - present?

Comment: @Lucia All of the Animals with a particular brownBearId

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can do this and this answer assumes that the classes in question are properly mapped JPA entities.

The first approach is to use straight Spring Data Repositories, here is an implementation that will achieve what you want.

```
public interface AnimalRepository extends JpaRepository<Animal, String> {
  Animal findByBears_BrownBears_Id(String id);
  Animal findByBearsBrownBearsId(String id);
}
```

Personally, I think if I were doing this I would ensure that these entities have bi-directional mappings and go about it from the bottom up, e.g.

```
public interface BrownBearRepository extends JpaRepository<BrownBear, String> {

}
```

Then, getting back to the `Animal`, given the BrownBear id would simply be

```
BrownBear brownBear = brownBearRepository.findById("some id").orElseThrow(EntityNotFoundException::new);
Animal animal = brownBear.getBear().getAnimal();
```

Comment: So, the only entity/table is the Animal class itself. The other sub set<> objects are simply Data Transfer Objects (DTO) that are not jpa entities with any mappings. In our database, the bears & dogs columns are stored as CLOBs. So, I don't think I can use this solution unfortunately. Do you have any other suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query for this:

```
select a 
from Animal a 
where exists(
    select 1
    from a.bears b
    join b.brownBears bb
    where bb.brownBearId = ?1
)
```